# text-align:center doesn't work but every other properties do

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm pretty new with HTML and wanted to create a simple page but I when i wanted to align my text, it doesn't follow the text-align instruction, but every other one is followed, here's the HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <title>Freelancers!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      <t class="center">Bienvenido a Freelancers!</t>
      <p>Para saber qué es un "freelancer", presiona 
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freelancer">
        <strong>aqui</strong>
        </a>. 
      </p>
      <st class="center">¿Quiénes somos?</st>  
        <p>
          Somos un grupo de estudiantes de la
          <a href="https://ucsp.edu.pe/"><strong>UCSP</strong></a>
          que aspiran a tener una página web donde las personas puedan acudir cuando necesiten de la ayuda de profesionales independientes, o "freelancers".
        </p>    
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS is here:

```
body{
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}
.center{
  text-align:center;

}
 t{
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Cambria,Courier, monospace;
 font-size:56px;

}
h1 st{
 color:rgb(148, 87, 87);
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Cambria,Courier, monospace;
 font-size:28px;
}

p{
 text-align:left;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-family:"Times New Roman", Arial;
 font-size:14px;
}
```

I'm sorry if the code is messy for you but I'm just trying to learn the language and if you got any recommendations I'll be grateful.

Comment: what is <t></t> and <st></st>

Comment: new tag are inline by default, you need to make the display:block and your text-align:center will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. Your `</h1>` is *way below where it should be. It should be directly after the heading. I've fixed in this fiddle.

   2. You can't just define html tags. I made your subheading an h3, and took away the `<t>` types out and it seems to be working perfectly.

```css
body{
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}
.center{
  text-align:center;

}
 t{
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Cambria,Courier, monospace;
 font-size:56px;

}
h1 {
 color:rgb(148, 87, 87);
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Cambria,Courier, monospace;
 font-size:28px;
}

p{
 text-align:left;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-family:"Times New Roman", Arial;
 font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="center">Bienvenido a Freelancers!</h1>
      <p>Para saber qué es un "freelancer", presiona 
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freelancer">
        <strong>aqui</strong>
        </a>. 
      </p>
      <h3 class="center">¿Quiénes somos?</h3>  
        <p>
          Somos un grupo de estudiantes de la
          <a href="https://ucsp.edu.pe/"><strong>UCSP</strong></a>
          que aspiran a tener una página web donde las personas puedan acudir cuando necesiten de la ayuda de profesionales independientes, o "freelancers".
        </p>
```

Comment: Oh!, I thought you could use the tags as "variables", damn now I feel bad, thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that in the way you intended. Glad we got it sorted though! :)

Would you mind marking it as 'answered' so it can help people in the future? Thanks!